# Javascript RegEx to return if string contains characters that are NOT in the RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have a user created string. I am only allowing the characters `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -,` and `_`

Using JavaScript, how can I test to see if the string contains characters that are NOT these? If the string contains characters that are not these, I want to alert the user that it is not allowed.

**What Javascript methods and RegEx patterns can I use to match this?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class. Use the following pattern along with the [`match` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]
```

Example:

```
var notValid = 'This text should not be valid?';

if (notValid.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_]/))
   alert('The text you entered is not valid.');
```

Comment: Thats the pattern, but what Javascript method can I use? Thank you

Comment: @John: read the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions and http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 6):

This one is straightforward:

```
if (/[^\w\-]/.test(string)) {
    alert("Unwanted character in input");
}
```

The idea is if the input contains even ONE disallowed character, you alert.

Comment: Just to clarify for people like me: `/[^\w\-]/` - this cotains the whitelist, meaning the list of allowed characters. To add something to it, append it after the dash, for example like so: `/[^\w\-äöÄÖ]/`.